# Can you make me understand how this query works?

Tags: sql, oracle11g

How is this where clause working?

```
SELECT ENAME,SAL 
FROM EMP E
WHERE 3 > (
    SELECT COUNT(*) 
    FROM EMP
    WHERE SAL > E.SAL
);
```

Comment: You should really add sample data, unless you are using Oracle's sample tables, and even in that case you might want to narrow it down a bit.

Comment: Probably not the most efficient query to get that answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query will return all employees for which there are strictly less than 3 other employees who have a higher salary.

For example, if you had the following set of employees and salaries:

```
Fred $100
Bill $80
John $60
Jack $50
```

Then your query would return everyone *except* for Jack, because Jack has 3 employees who have a higher salary than he does, but everyone else has 2 or less.

Note: Your query strictly does *not* return the three employees with the highest salaries, because it doesn't take duplicate salaries into account.  If you want a query to find the employees in the top 3 even in the presence of ties you can try this:

```
SELECT ENAME,SAL 
FROM EMP E
WHERE (
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT SAL) 
    FROM EMP
    WHERE SAL > E.SAL
) < 3
```